# How to get PHP CodeIgniter to re-insert "index.php" into the url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a very frustrating problem and would appreciate any help

Some months ago i configured my online server to remove index.php from the urls of pages on my online site. So any navigation did not require index.php in the middle of the url. But now i've transferred the live version of the site back to my PC and need to get it to work WITH index.php in the URL, so essentially i need to reverse changes i have made, but i can't seem to do it.

I can only vaguely recall what i did to make it work online WITHOUT index.php in urls, and it involved putting an .htaccess file into the site. This .htaccess file is in the site root and had this code in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I removed this code from the .htaccess file and restarted the apache server, but its still not working: every time i try to click a link to navigate to a page on the localhost version of my site, it tries to go to a url without index.php in it and then says the link is not found. What am I missing here?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: I have to ask, why do you need to add index.php back in the URL on your local server?

Answer (score 1):

The two changes you made are configuring your apache through `.htaccess` file which you reverted already and deleted the value of `index_page` in your `config.php`:

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; // it should be empty in your case
```

You should put it back to be able to use `index.php`

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

in config folder change config file where base_url is set as empty by default 
change the base_url and add index.php
like :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yourdomain/index.php';
```

it reinsert index.php in every base_url or site_url function.

after that the problem you face is you cannot load any asset file by calling common base_url and site_url functions.

i recommend you to add .htaccess file again. else you have to add index.php in your every single src or href tag.